# How to input images and npy files into VGG16 model for training with folder organization?

Tags: keras, input, deep-learning, concatenation, generator

I am would like to ask how to input image and npy files into the model at the same time.

Now I am trying to use the VGG16 model and want to Concatenate pictures and numpy arrays of 20.

The currently designed model is as follows,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHOT2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8ZWn.png)

The question now is how to input data, the following is the path where I put the file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLcxC.png)

The file folder (.png file) is the corresponding file folder (.npy file), which is a picture corresponding to a 20-dimensional feature to be used together for training (vgg16).

[image and numpy are different folders, but in the same order]

example: pic_test/fake/01_pic.png  correspond   feature_test/fake/01_npy.npy

as the same set of inputs

So I want to know, if I am in this path and use folders to distinguish fake or real, how should I use this double input model?

I tried ImageDataGenerator, but it seems to only work for images。

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

batch_size=8 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './pic_train',      
        target_size=(224,224),
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        class_mode='categorical'
        )

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './pic_test',
        target_size=(224,224),
        batch_size=batch_size, 
        class_mode='categorical'
        )
```

Comment: Please add screenshot to the questions, and format your code

Comment: sorry my reputation not enough to add screenshot